# extract text from pdf in php is not working for all PDF files

Tags: php, pdf, text-extraction, pdftotext

I am extracting text from PDF files. this is the code:

```
<?php

require("PdfToText.php");

$file   =  'SamplePF' ;
$pdf    =  new PdfToText ( "$file.pdf" ) ;
echo ( $pdf -> Text ) ;

?>
```

This class work fine for some PDF files.
The problem with this class is :

1. for some PDF files it take text from random page/line not in the
   page sequence wise.
2. for some PDF files it is not showing any result.
3. for some PDF files it extract only one or two lines.

Please suggest some solution. Thank You!

Comment: Some PDF files are older and don't use the same structure anymore. If you have issues with it, contact Adobe of why they have not published a public API for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this might be the exact problem because of which you are not able to extract but I also encountered something similar when extracting data from pdf. Sometimes the PDF files are locked by owner passwords which puts certain restrictions on the document and does not allow changing, content copying or extraction etc so as to protect its copyright issues. [Check this link for more info on owner passwords](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-a-pdf-owner-password-2619254).

So you can first try to remove owner password and then try to extract such pdf's. To remove owner passwords there are a number of tools available online, you can choose whichever fits you the best.